# Graph program in C

Tags: c

I want to write a code in which i want to know how much time is needed to move from one point to another.

Input

1) First line(input) is showing the maximum time required to reach

2) Second line(second and third input) shows the intial position.

3)Third line(fourth and fifth input) shows the final position.

4)fourth line shows the time taken to travel one step in left , right , up and down .

Output an integer denoting the time needs to reach, if not able to reach in time output a string Valar Codulis. Output the answer of each testcase on newline.

But my program is not running like this . why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int c, d, e, f, b;
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    scanf("%d", &d);
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d", &e);
    scanf("%d", &f);
    printf("\n");
    int g, h, i, j;
    scanf("%d", &g);
    scanf("%d", &h);
    scanf("%d", &i);
    scanf("%d", &j);

    int k, l, m, n, o;
    e - c == k;
    f - d == l;
    if (e - c >= 0, f - d >= 0)
    {
        m = k*h;
        n = l*i;
    }
    else if (e - c <= 0, f - d >= 0)
    {
        m = k*g;
        n = l*i;
    }
    else if (k >= 0, l <= 0)
    {
        m = k*h;
        n = l*j;
    }
    else
    {
        m = k*g;
        n = l*j;
    }
    o = m + n;
    if (b >= o)
    {
        printf("\n %d", o);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Valar Codulis");
    }
}
```

NOTE:I am a beginner.

Comment: `e-c==k;` This doesn't do anything. `if(e-c>=0,f-d>=0)` This doesn't do what you think it does. The comma is not a logical conjunction operator.

Comment: Also, it is very much allowed to use longer names. You don't *have to* wait until you need more than 26 variables.

Comment: Give variables real names not k,l,m...

Comment: `printf("\n");` is completely unnecessary. You're printing one character, so it's better to use `putchar('\n');`

Comment: slvnavcadhutuyp

Comment: @n.m. Can you please explain me why ?

Comment: 'Single letter variable names are very confusing and don't help us to understand your program'.

Comment: @IgorPavkovic I think it is not necessary

Comment: Agree with @n.m. Koolman, get any book, it is basic

Comment: @Koolman in this program not so much, in bigger programs very very necessary better learn now so you dont struggle later

Comment: @JacekCz you mean I should write if(e-c>=0,f-d>=0) this as if(k>=0,l>=0)

Comment: @IgorPavkovic okay , I will take care of this

Comment: down for this question, friend. Close SO and open any C tutorial. Wlecome here when You have real questions

Comment: See that book in the corner gathering dust - the one about C - perhaps read it.

Comment: @JacekCz yeah , I had watched the newboston tutorials

Comment: "I had watched the newboston tutorials". Great, now get a book.

Comment: @n.m. which book you would recommend

Comment: @n.m. if I write it as if(k>=0&&l>=0) , Then is it fine ?

Comment: @koolman - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @n.m. can you please help me . How can I print output consecutively of different test codes . https://pastebin.com/JgTLBBF7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
e - c == k;
```

This line of code has no effect. It checks whether the value of `e - c` is equal to that of `k` but nothing is done with the result of the check.

If you want to *assign* a value to `k`, use `k = e - c`. Likewise with `l = f - d.`

`if (e - c >= 0, f - d >= 0)` should be  `if (e - c >= 0 && f - d >= 0)`. Multiple conditions for an `if` statement cannot be joined using a comma. The logical operator `&&` means *'and'*.